# Is this a counter example of $E(X|X) = X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let's say I'm throwing a die and telling you whether the outcome is greater than 3 or not, then your task is to tell the conditional expectation of the outcome given this partial information.

Let's say I told you the outcome is bigger than $3$ (i.e. $X \in \{4, 5, 6\}$)... In this case the conditional expectation should be $5$

Isn't that contracting with $E(X|X)=X$?

Comment: I think you are mixing things here... How are you defining $X$? If you says that $X(\omega)\in\{4,5,6\}$ then $\Pr[X\le 3]=0$.

Comment: There is no contradiction. You have in mind the equality $E(X\mid X=x) = x$. (Majuscule is r.v., minuscule is a value.)

Comment: I am thinking of $X$ as all possible outcomes of the die.

Comment: Effectively we have that, for $X$ representing the outcome of a fair dice, $E[X|X\ge 4]=5$. But $E[X|X]=X$.

Comment: If we are conditioning on $X=x$ then it is clear, but if we are conditioning on $X$ lying in a set instead it becomes unclear. @mic

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing conditioning wrt to a *random variable* and conditioning wrt to *an event*.

Here you are conditioning wrt to an event:
$$E(X | X \in \{4,5,6\})$$

Instead, this is conditioning wrt to a random variable:
$$E(X | X)$$

You can look up how these objects are defined precisely, but the fact that you're confusing them is the main problem.

In particular, note that the expectation conditioned on an event is a *number*, while the expectation conditioned on a random variable is a *random variable*.

So yes, it is true that $E(X | X \in \{4,5,6\}) = 5$ and it is **also** true that $E(X | X) = X$. It is **not** true that $E(X | X \in \{4,5,6\}) = X$ (instead, it is equal to $5$ as mentioned earlier)

Comment: Okay but shouldn't they agree ? I mean shouldn't $E(X|X)=X$ be true for any value of $X$ ?

Comment: @MohammadDorgham Again, you're missing the definition of $E(X | X)$. It is actually defined as $E(X | \sigma(X))$, where $\sigma(X)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$. Intuitively it says that "If I know $X$, then I expect $X$ to be equal to $X$", which is correct. On the other hand, $E(X | X \in \{4,5,6\}$ is saying "If I know that $X$ is either 4, 5, or 6, what is the expectation of $X$ given this new information?". Those are different questions

Comment: I know that I am missing something but still the current explanation does not remove my confusion.

Comment: @MohammadDorgham Fair point. But the explanation is a little long so I would suggest reading the definition of conditional expectation (wrt to an event and wrt to a random variable) from a book on probability (Probability essentials, by jacob and protter, for example) or on wikipedia :)

Comment: For example you said that conditioning on a random variable is different than conditioning on event, while the conditional expectation is originally defined on sets, that is The conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$ is defined as $E[Y||\sigma{(X)}]$ and is denoted by $E[Y||X]$ where $\sigma{(X)}=\{\omega: X(\omega)\in B\}$ for Borel sets $B$ .. and conditional expectation is always a random variable.

Comment: @MohammadDorgham Note that $\sigma(X)$ is not a set of the sample space $\Omega$, it is a collection of sets of $\Omega$ with a certain property (i.e. is a $\sigma$-algebra). So the conditional expectation wrt to $\sigma(X)$ is defined in a different way than usual conditioning on an event (which is a set in the sample space $\Omega$). Your definition of of $\sigma(X)$ is wrong, and would result in $\sigma(X) = \Omega$